# Is it possible to stop two male cats from fighting?

Tags: cats, behavior, aggression

I have two male cats with two female cats. The problem is that the older male cat is hurting his 6 month old male kitten.
What should I do to stop the older one from doing this ?

Comment: Is everyone spayed and/or neutered?

Comment: You can try treating this like any other undesired behavior -- I try to tell my too "no" when they're fighting (as opposed to when they are just arguing or playing;  it's a fine line), but I suspect all that will do is move the fight out of your sight. You can try re-introducing them from the most basic starting point,  but this may be something you just need to let them figure out. If they aren't doing damage to each other, that may be a better answer.

Comment: @JamesJenkins They are all normal and we did nothing to them.

Comment: @keshlam What do you mean by re-introducing them, I didn't understand you.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest that you spay/neuter all 4 of them.

This will not only likely solve the aggression problem but also prevent the problem of producing about 8 kittens twice a year.

That's 16 kittens per year on average in the first year. Then the next year each of the kittens, say half of them are female, will produce 16 kittens itself. That's 16 kittens from the first two mother cats plus 8*16=128 kittens from the second generation cats.

That's 144 cats in year two. And so on.

If you love cats do the world some good and pay for surgery in order to prevent future unnecessary suffering.

Comment: I can't neuter all of them, every time they make kittens we will sell them when they are grown to a good level.

Comment: @AsadMarmash I see. So you're a pedigree cat breeder then? What breed are you breeding?

Comment: The cat that I am talking about is angora, so it might be better if I neuter it because the little cat is somekind of pure persian, so it will help to get better kittens.

Answer (score 1):

You should neuter the adult male cat. Then you should begin behavior modification as suggested by keshlam in the comment that he should be creating as an answer soon.